# Excel VBA: How to insert pictures from URLs?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet structured in this way:

```
A    |B   |C
-------------
Item1|Url |
Item2|Url |
Item3|Url |
```

what I need to achieve is to read each URLs and get the image into every cell in the C column. My code right now is the follow:

```
Sub sg()
Dim i As Integer
Dim urlImg As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rowCount As Long
rowCount = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
MsgBox (rowCount)


For i = 2 To rowCount
    urlImg = Cells(i, 3).Value
    Cells(i, 3).RowHeight = Range("b" & i).offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Top + 5
    alto = Range("b" & i).offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Top + 5
    sinistra = Range("b" & i).offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Left + 5
    ridimensionamentoAltezza = Range("b" & i).offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Height - 10
    ridimensionamentoLarghezza = Range("b" & i).offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=0).Width - 10


    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(urlImg)
        .Top = alto
        .Left = sinistra
        .Height = ridimensionamentoAltezza
        .Width = ridimensionamentoLarghezza
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

And so far is working, I can get the images but of course right now is putting all the pictures on top of each others... I can't find a way to place every images one after anoter... any help?

Comment: You say the Url is in column B but in your code you get it from column F and also get the row height from column J... ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Yeah sorry..it was just for easy writing here.. F=B and J=C.. I'm sorry

Comment: @RobinMackenzie edited, thanks for noticed that

Comment: I tested your code and it works, the images are positionned on their corresponding row and not on top of each other like you said. So I dont understand what the problem is